# Table inside form and both inside modal in Twitter Bootstrap does not display right, padding are missing

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a situation here and perhaps solution is simple but I can't find a way out until now so I need some help.

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="selectFabricante" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="selectFabricante" aria-hidden="false" data-backdrop="static" style="display: block; padding-right: 17px;"><div class="modal-backdrop fade in" style="height: 611px;"></div>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Cerrar</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Seleccione uno o más fabricantes</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="fabForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal bv-form" novalidate="novalidate"><button type="submit" class="bv-hidden-submit" style="display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px;"></button>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table table-condensed">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th><input type="checkbox" id="toggleChkSelFabricante" name="toggleChkSelFabricante"></th>
                                    <th>Fabricante</th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="selFabricanteBody"><tr data-idproductosolicitud="1" data-id="1"><td><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="fabLinkChoice[]" value="1"></label></div></td><td>Dist1</td><td>DR</td><td class="has_pais fabTd-1"><span id="14">México</span>, <span id="15">Nicaragua</span>, <span id="16">Panamá</span></td><td>1212212</td></tr><tr data-idproductosolicitud="1" data-id="1"><td><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="fabLinkChoice[]" value="1"></label></div></td><td>Dist1</td><td>DR</td><td class="has_pais fabTd-1"><span id="14">México</span>, <span id="15">Nicaragua</span>, <span id="16">Panamá</span></td><td>1212212</td></tr></tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Regresar</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="" id="btnAgregarSelFabricante"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Agregar</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which render as image below shows:

[image]

What can be wrong in that markup? I'm using latest version of Twitter Bootstrap. Any help? Advice?

*Some clarifications:*

- I need the table inside the form because it's tabular data and semantic I think this is the right choice
- I need the form because I'm using [BootstrapValidator](http://formvalidation.io/) plugin and as says [here](http://formvalidation.io/getting-started/#writing-form) in docs that the right markup, and I need to check at least one checkbox is checked before enable the submit button and allow send the form

Comment: there is a problem with your bootstrap your simple works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/3060/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the element `<div class="form-group">` and its end tag surrounding `<div class="table-responsive">`. That will fix the padding issue. You also have an issue with the `checkbox` class. If you remove the `checkbox` class from the `<div>` containing the checkbox it'll align properly.